# 'ARMEABI' not targeted by this project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am new to Android development and have been setting up Andriod Studio and am getting this warning. The build runs fine aside from this.

WARNING: ABIs [arm64-v8a,armeabi-v7a,armeabi] set by 'android.injected.build.abi' gradle flag contained 'ARMEABI' not targeted by this project.

Any idea what's going on?